# Image of the standardization of permutations of a finite multiset

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, multisets

Let $M$ be a multiset $\{1^{m_1},2^{m_2},...\}$ whose cardinality $\#M:=m_1+m_2+...=:n$. Let $\Sigma:S_M\to S_n$ be the standardization map defined in Stanley combinatorics volume 1 ($S_M$ is the set of permutations of $M$). The author states in the solution of exercise 56 that
$$\text{Im}(\Sigma)=\{\sigma\in S_n:D(\sigma^{-1})=\{m_1,m_1+m_2,...\}\cap [n-1]\}.$$
But this just seems wrong. Let $M=\{1^2,2^1,3^2\}$ so $\#M=5$. Then let $w\in S_M$ be
$$w=12313$$
Applying standardization we get
$$\Sigma(w)=13425$$
The inverse permutation of $\Sigma(w)$ is $14235$ and its only descent is $\{2\}$. I think that the condition should be relaxed to $D(\sigma^{-1})\subseteq\{m_1,m_1+m_2,...\}\cap [n-1]$

Comment: It appears to me you are correct, that what Stanley wrote is wrong. I cannot think of how to fix it, though.

Comment: Isn't my fix correct? Since the image of the standardization is exactly made of the permutations $\sigma$ such that $D(\sigma^{-1})\subseteq \{m_1,m_1+m_2,...\}\cap [n-1]$ the reasoning of the proof still holds in the same way.